# How to install Client SDK and Informix server inside one VM?

Tags: informix

> *To be clear... My goal is to install Connection Manager and Informix Server inside one VM.*

I installed Informix 14.10 and Informix Client SDK. Informix server is installed in `/opt/ibm/infomix` and Client SDKin `/opt/ibm/csdk`. The reason for this is, that when I installed both to `/opt/ibm/informix`, the Client SDK I installed later, overwrote some files installed by the Informix server which caused some issues with the server.
I found somewhere it is better to install them separately (in different locations).

Now I have a different issue. I set the INFORMIXDIR to `/opt/ibm/informix`, but then, when I try to start the `oncmsm`, I see the following error.

```
[informix@db21 ~]# oncmsm -h
Failed to load error messages, please check your INFORMIXDIR
```

I found, that this may be cause by the `msgfile` in the `bin` directory.

```
[informix@db21 csdk]$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/csdk/bin/
[informix@db21 csdk]$ msgfile 
/opt/ibm/informix/msg/en_us/0333/
[informix@db21 csdk]$ oncmsm -h
Failed to load error messages, please check your INFORMIXDIR
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/csdk/bin/msgfile 
    
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/informix/bin/msgfile
/opt/ibm/informix/msg/en_us/0333/
[informix@db21 csdk]$ export INFORMIXDIR="/opt/ibm/informix"
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/informix/bin/msgfile
/opt/ibm/informix/msg/en_us/0333/
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/csdk/bin/msgfile 
 
[informix@db21 csdk]$ export INFORMIXDIR="/opt/ibm/csdk"
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/csdk/bin/msgfile 
/opt/ibm/csdk/msg/en_us/0333/
[informix@db21 csdk]$ /opt/ibm/informix/bin/msgfile
/usr/informix/msg/english/
[informix@db21 csdk]$
```

It looks like it should work when I change the `$INFORMIXDIR` to the `csdk` folder, but then...

```
[informix@db21 csdk]$ onstat -
Unable to read $INFORMIXDIR (/usr/informix).
```

Regarding the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=sdk-installation-owner), it should be possible to install both, Client SDK and Server under one user (`informix`).
Do you please know what is the issue here and how to make it works?

Comment: What is the Client SDK version? For Informix 14.10.x the matching version of CSDK is 4.50.x and it is common practice for these to be installed in the same directory. Historically it was usual to install CSDK first followed by the engine but these days it should not matter.
Do you have any environment variables set, such as CLIENT_LOCALE, which may influence the search for message files?
You could try using the truss / strace utilities with a command such as oncmsm to show which message files it is trying to locate.

Comment: You are right @SimonRiddle. I installed version 4.10. I will try version 4.50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informix version 14.10 was installed with SDK version 4.10. For v14.10 it is necessary to use Client SDK version 4.50.